# How to push code from gitlab to slave node using JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, master-slave

I have one master and multiple slave nodes, Master and nodes are the connection established. How can I push the code from gitlab to my slave nodes using Jenkins in master?

Answer (score 0):

```
node("slave-label") {
    stage("Git Checkout") {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
             branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
             doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
             extensions: [], 
             submoduleCfg: [], 
             userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@gitlab.com']]])
       }
    }
}
```